# How to add Laravel cron job entry Into server?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

From last 2 days i am trying to setup Laravel cron job in my server.
I have tried to add cron job into server but it is not working.

Cron Command i have tried to run every minute:

```
/usr/local/bin/php/home/prismati/hrms/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&
```

Kernel.php:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\AttendanceAlert::class
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->command('log:unmarked_attendance')->everyMinute();
}
```

Command File:

```
protected $signature = 'log:unmarked_attendance';

protected $description = 'Alert!';


public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle(){
    \Log::info('Testing Cron Job');
}
```

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/php/home/prismati/hrms/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&` is not a valid cron entry. You need to prepend `* * * * *` to make it run every minute.

Comment: Also: `/usr/local/bin/php/home/prismati/hrms/artisan` is probably missing a space and should be `/usr/local/bin/php /home/prismati/hrms/artisan`

Comment: fyi, there's a section in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) on how to set up cron jobs/scheduling for Laravel

Comment: Will you please have a look on this CRON JOB i have added into my server              https://prnt.sc/pnj0e9

Comment: Problem fixed: it was just a space issue between /php/       I have changed it to /php /